# How can I export to csv using pandas pd.read_sql?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python function that queries a database, how can I write this to csv when I do not convert to dataframe? Or must I import dataframe and use that function?

Return works fine to see results in my consol, but now I would like to export as csv.

any help would be appreciated.

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc, os 
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import numpy as np


    def date(businessDate):
        con = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN='+'Stack',autocommit=True)  
        print('working')


        sql = f"""
        SELECT * FROM date 
        where businessDate = {businessDate}

        """

        df_date = pd.read_sql(sql,con)

        con.close()

        return(df_date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears `df_date = pd.read_sql(sql,con)` produces a dataframe. You can test this by running `type(df_date)`.

See function below `write_to_csv()` which is essentially the same function as `date()` with `df_date.to_csv()` function. Ensure the csv file already exists before running `write_to_csv()` since this function will only write to it and not create it.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc, os 
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import numpy as np


def date(businessDate):
    con = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN='+'Stack',autocommit=True)  
    print('working')
    sql = f""" 
    SELECT * FROM date 
    where businessDate = {businessDate}
    """
    df_date = pd.read_sql(sql,con)
    con.close()
    return(df_date)

path = "C:\\Users\\path\\to\\your\\folder\\file.csv"

def write_to_csv(businessDate):
    con = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN='+'Stack',autocommit=True)  
    print('working')
    sql = f""" 
    SELECT * FROM date 
    where businessDate = {businessDate}
    """
    df_date = pd.read_sql(sql,con)
    con.close()
    df_date.to_csv(path)
    return('Successfully wrote to csv')
```

Comment: Thanks Angel. Can you explain to me how and where in the code it become a dataframe?  Also why is `path` in the first function?

Comment: `df_date = pd.read_sql(sql,con)` should produce a dataframe.  You can test this by running `type(df_date)` and it should return `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`. Path will direct where the csv file is located and allows the function `df_date.to_csv()` to write to it.

Comment: thanks, could the `path` been stored in the `write_to_csv` function?

Comment: Yes you can store it in the `to_csv` function. `df_date.to_csv(C:\\path\\to\\file.csv)`

Comment: so much import for a simple task. why oh why python